# JpaItemWriter (inserting data with where clause ) - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using Spring Batch ,  from Below Table I am trying to read data from PRODUCT table where po_id=1001 and then trying to insert in same Table but with different po_id (for example 1002).

Table Structure

ORDER TABLE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuDKu.png)
PRODUCT TABLE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6xu2.png)

JpaCursorItemReader :- is reading data from PRODUCT Table  for Po_id=1001

```
public JpaCursorItemReader<Product> jpaCursorItemReader() {
        JpaCursorItemReader<Product> jpaCursorItemReader = 
                new JpaCursorItemReader<Product>();
        
        jpaCursorItemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(postgresqlEntityManagerFactory);
        
        jpaCursorItemReader.setQueryString("From Product where po_id= 1001");

        jpaCursorItemReader.setSaveState(true);
        
        return jpaCursorItemReader;
    }
```

JpaItemWriter :- I need help to insert Date in PRODUCT Table with Po_id=1002? HOW CAN I DO THAT with below code.

```
public JpaItemWriter<Product> jpaItemWriter()
    {
        JpaItemWriter<Product> jpaItemWriter = new JpaItemWriter<Product>();
    
        jpaItemWriter.setEntityManagerFactory(postgresqlEntityManagerFactory);
        return jpaItemWriter;
        
    }
```

Comment: Well you don't. You create a processor that returns the object you want to save.

Comment: Yes you need a processor to create new Product with the same information of the initial product to do this.

Comment: I tried , But its updating the current records with New PO_id  which I mention above .

Comment: I am having T_product Table from where I am reading data for PO_id 1001 and now I want to copy all corresponding data for po_id 1001 and insert same records with po_id=1002

Comment: Please help me , how can I achieve  this ?

Comment: I got the solution , I avoid mapping primary key in Item Processor-- and new records are been inserted in Table with new Po_id